# Error of java code when moving between Ubuntu and windows

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Well, I am using `IntelliJ` to develop a project. I put some of my `.java` files in the folder `src/model/`. I have to begin with `package src.model;`, in Ubuntu , in order to avoid error. While in windows I have to begin with `package model;`.

Does anyone know why this happens and how can I avoid changing my code when I switch between the two platforms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your content root is set to [something]/src in Ubuntu,  See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html#d2022811e128) to fix it.